# Multiple URL calls in same class

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone development could somebody help me out this problem ,From one week i am facing with one issue , that is i have multiple urls like below

```
for (int i=0;i<=[listingAffArray];i++)
    NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.holidayjuggle.net:7777/services/inventoryservice/%@/%@/stores/search?location=12.971598700000000000,77.594562699999980000,50",appDelegate.buyingAff,[appDelegate.listingAffArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

in this i am getting response from all the urls but in didfinishloading could not able to find which urls responsedata

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
if(connection){
    NSLog(@"connection is successfull "); 
}
else{
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{ 
    responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init]; 
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [responseData appendData:data]; 
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

in responsedata only last url data is there i put breakpoint and observed each url is calling in didfinishloading , when the second url is calling it is upadating with the secondurl call like that in responsedata last url data only is there .How to store each response data seperately

Thanks in advance

sivakumari

Answer (score 0):

Create an array in your class and store each `strResponse` in your array (using `addObject`).

Also, this doesn't make sense:

```
for (int i=0;i<=[listingAffArray];i++)
    NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.holidayjuggle.net:7777/services/inventoryservice/%@/%@/stores/search?location=12.971598700000000000,77.594562699999980000,50",appDelegate.buyingAff,[appDelegate.listingAffArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

The `[listingAffArray]` part should give you a compiler error and, even if that did work, you would be overwriting the same variable each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happen because all `NSURLConnection` share same delegate same object which is "self"

If u want to load multiple URL than you should have multiple space to store that data.

So one object of responseData is not sufficient.

There can be many way let me suggest one which I use.

- Declare a `NSMutableDictionary` object
- Store `NSURLConnection` object as key and `NSMutableData` object as value so if u have 3 URL you have 3 entery in `NSMutableDictionary`.
- In every Delegate method of `NSURLConnection` append data only to corresponding `NSMutableData` object.

Tell me if u need more help....

Comment: Actually i didnt get your point how to store Nsurlconnection object

Answer (score 0):

Try to call web service with url in a asynchronous manner.
ie.Hit the first url and when you received the result of first url the hit the second url request. after that when u received the second url response hit the third url request.

These all request should run in background thread or a new thread, so that it doesn't effect the main thread.

Also take a enum data type like

```
enum {
  requestOne=0,
  requestTwo,
  requestThree,
  requestFour
}currentRequest;
```

when u start hitting  the first url in currentRequestData assign requestOne  and in response check wit this enumDataType. when response received then hit second url with seconod enum type